# Is there any program to see sniffed HTTP packets like a web browser?

Tags: wireshark, packet

Programs like Wireshark are used to sniff packets and with them it's possible to see content of HTTP request and response including HTML codes and etc. But analyzing these contents are really hard and will take a lot of time.

So is there any program (or plug-in for Wireshark) to see these HTTP packets like a real visual web browser?

Comment: If such a feature were available it would have to combine several packets to make up a full web page. (Bear in mind the multiple sources that make up a web page.) Plugging a web browser on a single HTTP packet will produce but an incomplete page; is that what you want?

Comment: @Nasha that would be better than nothing :D isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firefox, there's a ["LiveHTTP headers" plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) that does that sort of thing. It's only the headers, but it does include request and response for every single HTTP interaction, which can be tedious.

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to see HTTP headers. I think you misunderstood my question.